# Missing permission when trying to get current location using fusedLocationClient

Tags: android, android-studio, android-location, fusedlocationproviderclient

Good afternoon! I'm trying to get geolocation using this official guide: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java)
As written in the guide, I added this at the beginning of the class:

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
```

Also I added this code in **onCreateView**:

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        longText.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
                        latText.setText("latitude: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
                    }
                }
            });
```

I added this to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And I added this in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```

But I am getting two errors:

```
Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
Cannot resolve method 'addOnSuccessListener(com.maxet24.chargely.ListFragment, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<android.location.Location>)'
```

Here is the whole code:
ListFragment.java
https://pastebin.com/bU5Ek80K 
fragment_list.xml: https://pastebin.com/zsMuT1Pe 
AndroidManifest.xml: https://pastebin.com/J505ALA7

Answer (score 0):

Do you grant those 2 permission (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) before calling mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()?

Edit:
[Request location permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)

Comment: How to do it? I only gave permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Check this: https://pastebin.com/GqdKrczk
Same error.

Comment: You approve those permissions and still got the same error?
Do you calling mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() after the premissions where granted? (in your case in line 47)

Comment: So I have to call a mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() in line 47?

Comment: You firstable need to ask the user to grant location permissions.
Only after he grant this persmission, you can use mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().
In line 47 it sais "// Precise location access granted." -> the user grant the permission

Comment: Now i call function after request, but i get same error.
https://pastebin.com/73bLZTnR

Comment: Here is a project of mine were i'm using mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() (in MainActivity)
https://github.com/EvyatarKohn/TravelMaker
Maybe it will be more helpful

Comment: Thanks, but i use Java.

Answer (score 0):

I just ignored this error and the program works fine on the phone.
**Alt + Enter -> Suppress** 
But still, it's weird.